# ASP.NET MVC 5 Routing configuration not checking assigned folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, routes

I am having some trouble using the ASP routing engine, the issues are self pretty self explanatory.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "GameGold",
        url: "Products/GameGold/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Coins", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

And when I go to the URL localhost/Products/GameGold/Coins/ this is what appears.

```
The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Coins/Index.aspx
~/Views/Coins/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/Coins/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Coins/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
```

I have my folders laid out like this

/Views/Products/GameGold/Coins/Index.cshtml

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error that your "`Index`" view had not been found was not caused by the routing definition.

The URL `localhost/Products/GameGold/Coins/` was mapped by the ´GameGold´ route to the `CoinsController`and its `Index`action.

The built in convention for MVC is to look up the view in the `~/Views/[CONTROLLERNAME]` folder - so it looked inside the `~/Views/Coins/` folder`.

To fix this you have two options:

1.) Stick to the convention and move the `/Views/Products/GameGold/Coins/Index.cshtml` to `/Views/Coins/Index.cshtml`

2.) Change the `ViewLocationFormats` of the Razor engine to accomodate your directory layout. Details for this you can find in blogs posts like http://www.ryadel.com/en/asp-net-mvc-add-custom-locations-to-the-view-engine-default-search-patterns/
An example from this post:

```
// Add /MyVeryOwn/ folder to the default location scheme for STANDARD Views
var razorEngine = ViewEngines.Engines.OfType<RazorViewEngine>().FirstOrDefault();
razorEngine.ViewLocationFormats = 
    razorEngine.ViewLocationFormats.Concat(new string[] { 
        "~/Views/Products/GameGold/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
        "~/Views/Products/GameGold/{0}.cshtml"
        // add other folders here (if any)
    }).ToArray();
```